# Disable Browser Input Field Effects?

Tags: html, css, input, focus

Okay, I'm trying to get rid of all these little things browsers do to input fields (like focus borders and what not).

```
input[type="text"] {
    font:bold 10px/12px verdana,arial,serif;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px; 
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none!important; 
}
```

The code above does not work. I also tried editing the input via the 2.1 way (

```
input.text { /*stuffhere*/};
input.text:focus{ outline: none; }
```

). It didn't work. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using? `outline: none !important;` works in Chrome & Safari for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm at a loss; you seem to be doing it correctly. Border for the normally-visible border, and outline for the focusy thing.

Have a look at this fiddle and see if it's working as expected. If it does (as it does for me), it could be conflicting CSS in your case. !important is a dangerous and powerful tool, but it's still no guarantee.

http://jsfiddle.net/LQppm/1/

```
input[type="text"] {border: none}
input[type="text"]:focus {outline: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `outline: 0!important;` will work?

Comment: Both `outline: none!important;` and `outline: 0 !important;` auto insert missing values in such a way so as to resolve to the same thing.